# Can we create an auto increment number sequence on Azure Cosmos Mongo DB API

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, auto-increment, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Can we create an auto increment number sequence on Azure Cosmos Mongo DB API?

Comment: MongoDB does not have out-of-the-box auto increment functionality, like SQL databases. Check this reference document it may helps https://data-flair.training/blogs/mongodb-auto-increment-sequence/

Comment: @vijaya - that article suggests a JS function resulting in a single-point bottleneck.

Comment: There is no auto-increment. And this has been discussed in other questions as well, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54478715/272109). I suggest looking into guids, to remove all of the problems related to this.

Answer (score 0):

No, unlike SQL databases that have this functionality natively, NoSQL databases don't let you create a auto incremental field.

You could create a query to select all the items in the collection and just use it the amount of documents that were returned. I don't think it would have a good performance when your solution reach out a big amount of data, but it could work temporarily.